# Is FCC/CE recertification needed if only the product name is changing?

Tags: fcc, certification, ce

I got FCC/CE certification for my product (a music player, unintentional radiator), but would now like to put out the same product under a new name. Nothing else is changing (PCB design, casing, etc. are all staying the same). Do I need to re-certify the product?

If recertification is not required, does the new product name need to be filed/registered in some way or can it be distributed as-is?

Comment: I do not have experience. Why not ask the regulator body you tested with by email?

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a name change for marketing purposes you probably don't need to do anything. If you export the product to countries with pedantic Customs however, you'll probably want the same name in the test report.

Either way, if nothing in the actual product has changed, it should be sufficient for the test house you used to issue a new edition of the test report. They will typically just bill you by the hour for the paperwork then.